# Scalaz - Unable to unapply type StateT[Future, Foo, Bar]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I had a list `l` of `StateT[Id, MyState, Boolean]`.

With it i was able to do the following:

```
case class MyState (s: String)

val startState = MyState ("s")

val l: List[StateT[Id, MyState, Boolean]] = ...

val failed = l.sequenceU.map { x => }
 .map { _.foldMap (identity)(Monoid.instance (_ | _, false)) }
 .eval (startState)
```

This would pipe the state through everything in the list, one by one, and then combine all the results with a bitwise OR (|).

I now want to change my list to be of type `StateT[Future, MyState, Boolean]`, however I am struggling to get it to compile.  The compiler cannot work out what I need to to do to get it to compile.  The compiler tells me that I need to be able to compile `implicitly[Unapply[Applicative, StateT[Future, MyState, MyResult]]]`, which right now I cannot, my question is how can I implicitly define what I need?

The following reproduces the error on the REPL:

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import scalaz.Id._
import scalaz.Id._

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> case class MyState (s: String)
defined class MyState

scala> case class MyResult (r: String)
defined class MyResult

scala> implicitly[Unapply[Applicative, StateT[Id, MyState, MyResult]]]
res0: scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Applicative,scalaz.StateT[scalaz.Id.Id,MyState,MyResult]] = scalaz.Unapply_2$$anon$5@5443fcf1

scala> implicitly[Unapply[Applicative, StateT[Future, MyState, MyResult]]]
<console>:55: error: Unable to unapply type `scalaz.StateT[scala.concurrent.Future,MyState,MyResult]` into a type constructor of kind `M[_]` that is classified by the type class `scalaz.Applicative`
1) Check that the type class is defined by compiling `implicitly[scalaz.Applicative[<type constructor>]]`.
2) Review the implicits in object Unapply, which only cover common type 'shapes'
(implicit not found: scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Applicative, scalaz.StateT[scala.concurrent.Future,MyState,MyResult]])
              implicitly[Unapply[Applicative, StateT[Future, MyState, MyResult]]]
                        ^
```

Interestingly the following compiles:

```
 scala> implicitly[Unapply[Applicative, StateT[Option, MyState, MyResult]]]
res2: scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Applicative,scalaz.StateT[Option,MyState,MyResult]] = scalaz.Unapply_2$$anon$5@265a640
```

Which leaves me to think it must be something to do with it `StateT` being typed on `Future`, perhaps something for `Future` is not defined?

I am using Scalaz 7.0.5, which I know doesn't have `Monad[Future]`, however I am importing:

https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib/blob/v0.1.5/scala210/main/scala/Future.scala

Also, I've tested this out on a REPL with Scalaz 7.1.0 and I get the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but... you actually need to have an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope:

```
scala> import scalaz.contrib.std.scalaFuture._
import scalaz.contrib.std.scalaFuture._

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> implicitly[Unapply[Applicative, StateT[Future, MyState, MyResult]]]
res14: scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Applicative,scalaz.StateT[scala.concurrent.Future,MyState,MyResult]] = scalaz.Unapply_2$$anon$5@4c167067
```

In this particular case, `Unapply` needs an `Applicative` instance for `Future` and that's provided by [this method](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib/blob/v0.1.5/scala210/main/scala/Future.scala#L11), which requires an `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: As an alternative you can use scalaz's own `Future` to avoid the need for this.

Comment: Sweet, this does indeed work in 7.1.0, however I can't get it to work with 7.0.5 with the scalaz-contrib Future file I posted above.

Comment: @Pooky works for me. Have you imported `scalaz.contrib.std.scalaFuture._`?

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had `import scalaz.contrib.std._`  Wizard!